# resin-maven-plugin:4.0.14:run:Cannot find setter, adder nor field in com.caucho.maven.MavenRun for 'contextRoot'

Tags: maven-plugin, resin

In maven web project :

when I click Plugins-> resin:run 
the console has some  error  message :
Failed to execute goal com.caucho:resin-maven-plugin:4.0.14:run (default-cli) on project sohutw-ginkgo-manage-web: Unable to parse configuration of mojo com.caucho:resin-maven-plugin:4.0.14:run: Cannot find setter, adder nor field in com.caucho.maven.MavenRun for 'contextRoot' -> [Help 1]

Idea:IntelliJ IDEA

pom.xml content is relevant code :
 `<plugin>
          <groupId>com.caucho</groupId>
          <artifactId>resin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>4.0.14</version>
              <configuration>
                 <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                 <port>8080</port>
              </configuration>
           </plugin>`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

it's called contextRoot, not path

Comment: jens: do you say, that fuyou001 can solve the problem, by renaming the element contextPath to contextRoot? Your answer is very very short, please elaborate a little bit.

Comment: Short and to the point... I like the answer. Don't bother elaborating on simple typos someone made.

Comment: @Jens I am setting "contextRoot" but I still get the same error with Resin Maven plugin version 4.0.16 in NetBeans. Any ideas/help, please?